# Python validate for A-Z or a-z

Tags: python, validation

I'm trying to create a demonstration program that checks the username entered of the user and validates it to check if it contains letters from A-Z or a-z.

```
user_boolean = False

while user_boolean == False:
    username = input("What is your name?")

    if [username contains letters] == False:
        username_reattempt = input("Your name contains numbers or unpermitted characters. Please type your name correctly. >> ")
        if username_reattempt[contains letters] == True:
            user_boolean == True
    else:
        user_boolean == True
```

Now, you can see that the user_boolean is set as false and that while it is false, this while loop will continue going. If the username contains characters that are not A-Z or a-z, then it will ask the user to retype their details. If they succeed the second attempt, they will exit the while loop and the program will continue into the main parts.

Now, I have researched into the different methods to doing this and so far I have not found a method... previously, I found the .isdigit() method, but that is for integers, not strings.

Is there a way?

Comment: Have you considered using Regular Expressions for this?

Comment: @Allendar regular expressions? That didn't come up, nope. What is that?

Comment: Check the `re` libraries; https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. You can easily validate patterns like this `r/[a-zA-Z]/`. You can use `find` or other variations to find the occurrences of how many a-zA-Z's are present in the string you're checking. In your case; if it's just more than `0` you have a truth.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a cookbook website Jack. Try reading the manual page I linked first and/or try Googling the millions of examples that are available on Google or any search engine. You would only need 2-3 lines of code to extend your program. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are unfamiliar with regular expressions, here's a super-easy alternative:

If  you want to whitelist only some characters (perhaps by allowing characters that are not just letters), then you would likely want to use a set:

```
def containsOnly(s, whitelist):
    whitelist = set(whitelist)
    for char in s:
        if char not in whitelist:
            return False
    return True
```

This function can be used for your purpose as follows:

```
In [7]: containsOnly('asdfA5', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
Out[7]: False

In [8]: containsOnly('asdfA', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
Out[8]: True

In [9]: containsOnly('asdfA5', '5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker: why do you say that? OP is clearly a beginner, so I wanted to write ultra simple code

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good catch. I had a slight logic bug in my conditions. They should be fixed now

Comment: Uh, no. Don't you test your code? First, at the very least it should be `>` instead of `>=`. But still any string will return False (because `A` fails the first condition, and `a` fails the second one)...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: bah! My head's clearly not in the game tonight. What do you think now?